# My usb flash drive (Lexar) has very important documents from my Grad.

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

The flash drive I am using for Graduate school (has my life on it) is telling me to format the drive.  I have already done this and if I do it again, I will lose all the data.  How do I fix this?

Comment: And now you've learned why having a single copy of data is a horrible idea. bjanssen's suggestion may save things, but in the future: Assume 1 copy is 0 copies. Email things to yourself, put them in dropbox, *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already formatted the thumb drive, you might have already destroyed your data.

Your best chance now is to recover all that is still readable, if any. TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is an excellent tool for this task and probably your best bet. Make sure to read the documentation BEFORE you start anything.

Good luck!